# Android Edittext errors disappearing after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm having a problem with the Android Edittext.
I have a form. If the validation is not successful, I set an error to the edittext with the method setError().

However, on some devices, when I rotate the screen, the error disappears.

I have looked everywhere, but can't seem to find the solution to that.

Any ideas ?

Comment: you could set a state variable to the edittext that you save in onSaveInstanceState() and retrieve in your onCreate() method and reset the error (or not) to the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the device your activity gets Re-Created, The previous instance of activity gets destroyed and new instance of activity is created followed by all the methods of activity life cycle. Check on which method you are showing error in EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below codes in your manifest..

```
 <activity
      android:name=".YourActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` attribute for your activity in  manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I thought android's view objects would handle this on their on, but they don't. So I think the solution is to save this information in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and restore it in onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) for example (if you are working with a subclass of Activity). Here's an example to illustrate:
Say you are working with a subclass of Activity and you have a login form with two edit texts, one for email and one for password.

```
    EditText mEmail = null;
    EditText mPassword = null;

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mEmail.setError( savedInstanceState.getString("email") );
            mPassword.setError( savedInstanceState.getString("password") );
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("email", mEmail.getError());
        outState.putString("password", mPassword.getError());
    }
```